# UIWebView download from <a href=myFileName.myFileType>

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, uiwebview, mime-types

I want my UIwebview to trigger a download of a file when it's link is clicked... It just opens it in the webview i.e. it renders the content of the file, a JSON-string.

- I have registrered the mimetype. I have tried adding
  download="target.myfiletype" to the anchor tag but it still just
  renders the content (json) in the UIWebview.
- When i send it in an email it just opens in the correct application as I want it to...

  How do i make my UIWebview(which is in the same app) trigger opening
  the file in my app, in the same manor as with the email?

The email source of the file part looks like this:

```
...
 --Apple-Mail-38441BAA-F4DD-4BF1-B2CC-9AF9C829566A
Content-Type: application/myfiletype;
    name="ExtremeSomething"
Content-Disposition: attachment;
    filename="ExtremeSomething"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

{
//FILECONTENT
}
...
```

My app implements file loading by the book, and it works when i click a file in an email:

```
-(BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {

    if (url != nil && [url isFileURL]) {
        [self loadFile:url];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

I have tried to override shouldStartLoadWithRequest with a negative return value:

```
//Load initial page:
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"http://users.student.lth.se/et08dc0/getWork.html"];
    [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]]];
    loadedNowDownloadMode = NO;
}

//Resort to download move where all <a> clicks result in downloads:
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    loadedNowDownloadMode = YES;
}

//Logic for overriding shouldStartLoadWithRequest:
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request
 navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    //Handle the download...
    NSURL* url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[[request URL] absoluteString]];
    [DELEGATE loadFile:url];

    //Prevent page load
    return !loadedNowDownloadMode;
}
```

In class referenced by macro DELEGATE:

```
-(void) loadFile:(NSURL*)url{
    NSError *error;
    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc]
                                     initWithContentsOfURL:url
                                     encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                     error:&error];
    if (jsonString == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Error reading file at %@\n%@",
              url, [error localizedFailureReason]);
        return;
    }
    NSLog(@"Should load file!");
    [self.coreDataHelper importNSData:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [((ListViewController*)listsViewController) reloadTableData];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can handle your specific urls in `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` delegate method, return `NO` and open content in your app

Comment: If I just set return no it fails to open the link I click at all, not in view not downloading... Something more todo? (See updated answer)

Comment: before return NO, you need put URL in code that handle it, should be the same as in AppDelegate

Comment: I updated my answer with a call to the appropriate delegate method :) Works!